# Path expansion for volume overlays uses root with Rancher Desktop (OSX)

Tags: docker-compose, nerdctl, rancher-desktop

We're trying to use rancher desktop and nerdctl to bring up some compose stacks. The issue we've run into is that when you have a mount similar to the following, nerdctl expands either `${HOME}` or `~/` to `/root`, despite me running the command as my normal user.

```yaml
        volumes:
            - ${HOME}/.config/conf:/opt/confpath
```

```
FATA[0000] failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/root/.config/conf" to rootfs at "/opt/confpath" caused: stat /root/.config/conf: no such file or directory: unknown 
FATA[0000] error while creating container u42-docs: exit status 1
```

Is there a way to prevent this path expansion to the root user, and instead be my own user?

Rancher desktop was installed via `brew install --cask rancher`